# I need to parse XML and display as autocomplete in the text field in PhoneGap using jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml, cordova, autocomplete, textbox

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />     
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="jquery-mobile/styles/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />      
        <script src="cordova.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="jquery-mobile/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="jquery-mobile/js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script>
function loadXMLDoc(url)
{
    window.plugins.Orientation.lock("portrait")
var xmlhttp;
var txt,x,xx,i;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        txt="<table border='1'><tr><th>Company</th><th>Country</th><th>City</th></tr>";
    x=xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("CD");
    for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
      {
      txt=txt + " <tr>";
      xx=x[i].getElementsByTagName("COMPANY");
        {
        try
          {
          txt=txt + "<td>" + xx[0].firstChild.nodeValue + "</td>";
          }
        catch (er)
          {
          txt=txt + "<td> </td>";
          }
        }
      xx=x[i].getElementsByTagName("COUNTRY");
        {
        try
          {
          txt=txt + "<td>" + xx[0].firstChild.nodeValue + "</td>";
          }
        catch (er)
          {
          txt=txt + "<td> </td>";
          }
        }
          xx=x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE");
        {
        try
          {
          txt=txt + "<td>" + xx[0].firstChild.nodeValue + "</td>";
          }
        catch (er)
          {
          txt=txt + "<td> </td>";
          }
        }
      txt=txt + "</tr>";
      }
    txt=txt + "</table>";
    document.getElementById('txtCDInfo').innerHTML=txt;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>    
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--Home-->
        <div id="home" data-role="page" data-mini="true">
            <div data-role="header"  data-position="fixed"  data-tap-toggle="false">
                <h1>Welcome</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="info-wrapper">
                <div class="info-wrapper-left">
                    <img class="ice-logo"/>
                </div>

                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content">
                <ul data-role="listview" id="a" data-inset="true" data-theme="d">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#home1" data-transition="slide">
                            Services
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul data-role="listview" id="a" data-inset="true" data-theme="d">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#home2" data-transition="slide">Port</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul data-role="listview" id="a" data-inset="true" data-theme="d">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#home3" data-transition="slide">teasr</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul data-role="listview" id="c" data-inset="true" data-theme="d">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#home4" data-transition="slide">cvServices</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
        <!--Home End-->
        <!--programProgress page-->
        <div id="programProgress" data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true">
            <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed"  data-tap-toggle="false">
                <h1>Progress</h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <ul data-role="listview" id="Ul3" data-inset="true" data-theme="d">
                    <li>Coming Soon!</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div id="**search**" data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true">
            <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
                <h1>Service Company Search</h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
               <form id="search" action="#samp">
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="company">Company</label>
                        <input type="text" id="company" name="company" class="required company" />
                    </div>

                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="country">Country</label>
                        <input type="text" id="country" name="country" class="required" />
                    </div>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="city">City</label>
                        <input type="text" id="city" name="city" class="required" />
                    </div>
                     <div class="ui-body ui-body-b">
                        <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
                            <div class="ui-block-a">
                                <button id="btnCancel" data-theme="d">Cancel</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ui-block-b">
                                 <a href="#samp" data-transition="slide"><button onclick="loadXMLDoc('cd_catalog.xml')">SEARCH</button></a>        
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                     </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
         <!--Service Company Search End-->
    <div id="samp" data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true">
            <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
                <h1>Service Company Search</h1>
            </div>
             <div id="txtCDInfo" data-role="content">

            </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the Phonegap Application. Here I need to use autocomplete the textbox with the xml file using javascript or jquery.

For instance take  **country** field when i start typing the country it should auto complete the list in the xml filtering the particular letter typed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery auto complete widget. Refer below links for further readings. Let me know if you find any problems to use this.

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: Hi tkz for the reply the list of keyword here is static i need to retrive it from xml what can i do

Comment: and for jquery mobile will it be suitable. i am new to phonegap development

Comment: Yes it is suitable for jquery mobile. And you can set source of data please read http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source for the same.

Comment: <label for="autocomplete">Select a programming language: </label>
<input id="autocomplete">
 
<script>
$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
  source: [ "c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby" ]
});
</script>  this code i have used but its not working dude